# Use a Template method in place of repeated code

Tags: c#, templates, generics, reusability

I have 4 methods which have similar code

```
private void LogExceptions(ObjA.Input input, int customerId)
{
    //ObjA is a big object, thats why I try not to send the whole object in this method
    Log(input);
    Log(ObjA.Exceptions);
}

private void LogExceptions(ObjB.Input input, int customerId)
{
    //ObjB is a big object, thats why I try not to send the whole object in this method
    Log(input);
    Log(ObjB.Exceptions);
}
```

and so on

I am not able to make it a template method such as

```
private void LogExceptions<T1,T2>(T1 input, int customerId) whereas     T1:ObjA.Input,ObjB.Input
{
    Log(T1);
    Log(T2);
}
```

How to do it or is there any other way ?
Any help is appreciated in advance .

I don't think my question was helping get proper answers....
Here is the exact code....

```
    private void LogExceptions(AccARef.Response response)
    {
        StringBuilder sbErrors = null;

        if (response.ValMethod != null && response.ValMethod.IsValid == false)
        {
            if (response.ValMethod.Errors.Count() > 0)
            {
                sbErrors = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (AccARef.Exception exp in response.ValMethod.Errors)
                {
                    sbErrors.Append(" * " + exp.Message + exp.StackTrace + " ");
                    Console.WriteLine(strError.ToString())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void LogExceptions(AccBRef.Response response)
    {
        StringBuilder sbErrors = null;

        if (response.ValMethod != null && response.ValMethod.IsValid == false)
        {
            if (response.ValMethod.Errors.Count() > 0)
            {
                sbErrors = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (AccBRef.Exception exp in response.ValMethod.Errors)
                {
                    sbErrors.Append(" * " + exp.Message + exp.StackTrace + " ");
                    Console.WriteLine(strError.ToString())
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now AcctBRef and AcctARef cannot implement a common interface as they are not my objects. Or if they are no my objects, can I still decorate them to be mine ?

Comment: What do you mean by your comment about "send the whole object"?  Class instances are [**passed by value-reference**](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html), which means there is very little data (a pointer) getting passed around from method to method no matter how big the object is.

Comment: Is `ObjB.Exceptions` a static call?

Comment: Also, is "Input" an inner class to both ObjA and ObjB??

Comment: ObjA.Exceptions is just an example as I cannot put real code which will not make sense to you.

Comment: Input is an inner class but they are both separate and coming from different namespaces but have exactly same properties. The reason I can't change them or have a common interface as they are coming from a service response which is out of my control.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need generics in this case, if ObjA and ObjB either inherit from the same base blass or interface.

If you have

```
interface IBaseClass 
{
   IEnumerable<Something> Exceptions {get;set;}
   InputType Input {get;set;}
}
class A : IBaseClass {}
class B : IBaseClass {}
```

You can just use this for your LogExceptions signature:

```
void LogExceptions(IBaseClass obj, int CustomerId) 
{
   Log(obj.Exceptions);
   Log(obj.Input);
}
```

If they *don't* inherit from a common interface, then I suggest they should.

Comment: I know this trick...but ObjA and ObjB are out of my control, although they have exactly similar properties...they are different as they come from a 3rd party service.

Comment: then without reflection, you're stuck with an override for each ObjA/ObjB.  Adding an override for each type, in this case seeme cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass Type parameter to Log method. You have to pass an instance of Type parameter.

try following:

```
 private void LogExceptions<T1, T2>(T1 input, T2 exceptions, int customerId) 
    {
        Log(input);
        Log(exceptions);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I feel is if there are 4 methods and they don't have same method signature its completely fine, it doesn't always have to be generic it has to be readable as well.

Why would you make 4 calls `Log(T1),Log(T2),Log(T3),Log(T4)` if all you have to do is `Log(OneofTheTypeWhichYouKnowWhenCallingTheMethod)`.

Having said that you can always have reflection to play around like in your case.